# Highcharts Treemap: Add link on lowest level

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a possibility to add a hyperlink on the lowest level of a treemap?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/treemap-large-dataset/

```
 1. Click on Africa 
 2. Click on Nigeria
 3. Click on "Communicable Diseases" should be a link to e.g. www.google.com
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can realise this in that way:
1) set useHTML as true
2) catch datalabels formatter
3) Add condition, which check if this is "last level", by isLeaf flag
4) Return url as

Obviously you can extend this by keeping url in point object.

```
dataLabels: {
                useHTML:true,
                enabled: true,
                formatter:function(){
                    if(this.point.isLeaf) {

                        return '<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">' + this.key + '</div>';
                    } else {
                        return this.key;
                    }
                }
            },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7j03wx33/2/

Comment: Is there a possiblity to have one specific link for each of the leafs and how/where would I save them?

Comment: Add url field inside point and then use reference (in formatter) like this.point.options.url